# curl part in URL with awk or sed

Tags: url, curl, awk, sed

I have a part of an URL from a curl command like:

```
<span class="h2">Newest Version 2.1.4</span>
```

(The result is longer, but this should do it as well.
I want to have a sed or awk statement that leaves only

```
2.1.4
```

What is the most "dynamic" way to do that? Is it possible to filter only the Numbers after the word "Version" up to the

Comment: You need an HTML parser.

Comment: Your comments are all good but i have an ash, no bash. Also i have no xmlstarlet or xmllint. It's a script on a Synology NAS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) :

```
curl ...... |
xmllint --html --xpath '//span[@class="h2"]/text()' |
grep -oP 'Newest Version \K.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

*the most "dynamic" way* is not the case for that. You need the most robust and flexible way.

**`xmlstarlet`** solution:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'substring(//span[@class="h2"]/text(), 16)' -n input.html
```

The output:

```
2.1.4
```

---

Always use XML/HTML parsers when dealing with XML/HTML data.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `xmlstarlet` because it fails on real life html. `xmllint` or `saxon-lint` can parse html as well

Comment: @GillesQuenot, you are underestimating `xmlstarlet` ant its formatting/recovering posibilities

Comment: @GillesQuenot, instead, "your" `xmllint` has nothing to do with advanced editing/extracting

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command that must be piped to the command that will fetch your html file (`curl` or something else)

```
xmllint --html --xpath 'substring-after(//span[@class="h2"],"Newest Version ")' -
```

**Explanations:**

1. `--html` to activate the HTML parser mode
2. `--xpath` to evaluate an xpath expression, here the xpath expression is:
3. `'substring-after(//span[@class="h2"],"Newest Version ")'` is the xpath expression used to fetch from all the span elements the ones with attribute `class="h2"` then from that node you get the substring after `Newest Version`
4. Last but not least, it is important to use the `-` at the end to have `xmllint` work on `stdin` instead of working from a file.

**Test:**

```
$ echo '<span class="h2">Newest Version 2.1.4</span>' | xmllint --html --xpath 'substring-after(//span[@class="h2"],"Newest Version ")' -
2.1.4
```